# i get this error in console skel is not defined at main.js

Tags: javascript, skel

i uplaod my site to cpanel butits not opend and i get this error in my console :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: skel is not defined
> at main.js:10:5
> at main.js:114:3

and when i open main.js file i get this lines :

```
(function($) {

    skel.breakpoints({
        xlarge: '(max-width: 1680px)',
        large: '(max-width: 1280px)',
        medium: '(max-width: 1024px)',
        small: '(max-width: 736px)',
        xsmall: '(max-width: 480px)'
    });
```

note that the website is working in my pc .
[image]
[image]

Comment: You probably forgot to upload a JS file.

Comment: i upload all js file and its work fine on my pc

Comment: Well, check you uploaded it in the right place. And check the Network tool when loading the page to see if loading of the skelJS file failed. Because the error is clear - that skel code is not present in your page. So you need to re-check everything and don't make any assumptions.